# render a partial after a successful ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I have this jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/update_fb_user?fb_uid=" + FB.getSession().uid,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data){
    if(data.user != "none"){
        // here is where i need to render this partial
    }else{
        window.location.href = '/signup';
    }
 }
```

here is the partial call in the view

```
<div id="fb_iframe">
<% unless current_user.not_using_facebook? %>
    <%= render :partial => 'fb_iframe' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I was thinkng of just doing `fb_iframe`, but is there a way to either render the partial or recheck the `unless` block because the ajax call updates it so that the `unless` condition is true...any ideas on how to achieve either one or any way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your partial is already on the view (since you said you wanted to 'recheck the unless block'), looks like a reload to the page after the Ajax call succeeds is your solution.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/update_fb_user?fb_uid=" + FB.getSession().uid,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    if(data.user != "none"){
      window.location.reload();
    }else{
      window.location.href = '/signup';
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem, the partial lives on your server while the JavaScript is run client side. You need to get the rendered html from your server back to the client.  How you do this depends on whether the partial depends on your user model.

The two best options I can see are:

1. Return the partial as part of the `json` structure the `/update_fb_use` returns. Then say `$("#fb_iframe").html(data.html)`.
2. Include the partial in the original page as a JavaScript template using [jQuery](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/) or [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/).  Then, if you have a user, simply render the template.

The problem with approach 2 is that it may be hard to create a JavaScript template until you get enough data from the user.  It all really depends on what is in your partial.